Calculate % productivity dax formula
I have an excel file which contains the following columns: position (machine), company, workshop, date, article, quantity produced, quantity rejected, machine opening time. I want to calculate % productivity dax formula how to do it



position (machine)
company
workshop
date
article
quantity produced
quantity rejected
machine opening time




Bossar
Ind
GIAS1
1/2/2024
PFSN036
291
0
7.5


Hassia
Men
GIAS2
5/3/2024
PFV058
300
1
9



i have tried this :
%productivity = 
DIVIDE(
    SUM('Table'[quantity produced]),
    SUM('Table'[machine opening time]),
    0
)

but doesn't done the right result

Provide a sample of your data in Markdown format.

|position (machine)| company| workshop| date| article| quantity produced| quantity rejected| machine opening time.
Bossar | Ind|GIAS1|1/2/2024|PFSN036|291|0|7.5|
|Hassia|Men|GIAS2|5/3/2024|PFV058|300|1|9|

With the above table provided (I've added it to your question), what results are you getting and what are you expecting? Your expression above looks more like output per hour?

I want to calculate % productivity for each company dax formula

You need to define what % productivity means here, % of what?

maybe %produced quantity of items.

what's the expected output based on the sample data you provided?

I think you are looking for % produced by company for all produced?
You can use ALLSELECTED to return all rows filtered in the table.
Try:
% produced = 
  var allProduced = 
    CALCULATE(
      SUM('Table'[quantity produced]),
      ALLSELECTED('Table')
    )
  return
    DIVIDE(
      SUM('Table'[quantity produced]),
      allProduced,
      0
    )


do you have other suggestions for kpis to calculate

% rejected, output per hour, operating time by day/month, days not operating (downtime) etc..

Also, you are also missing the * 100 at the end to make it a percentage
try this:
Productivity Percentage = 
DIVIDE(
    SUM('Table'[Quantity Produced]) - SUM('Table'[Quantity Rejected]), 
    SUM('Table'[Machine Opening Time]), 
    0
) * 100

